# Adding "Delete" and/or "Mark as read" to mail notifications in Mavericks

Tags: mail.app, notifications

By default `maill.app` notifications has two buttons. One for replying to the email and the other one for closing the notification. This is very nice, although, I was wondering if there is any way that I can add either (or both) of the "Delete" and "Mark as read" buttons to the mail notifications. Applescript, hacking some settings, third party apps or any other ways are fine, however, I prefer some native built-in solutions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a free app called [Herald](http://erikhinterbichler.com/apps/herald/) which does have a Mark As Read button which I have used for a bit now and I can recommend as a stop-gap.

I dug around some `plist` files to see if anything related to this already exists. No luck, sadly. I also sent feedback to Apple using the link grgarside provided, if others do the same it may actually result in something!

Comment: Great extension, thanks. But how to disable standard notifications from mail app?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible in Mail's preferences. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html

Answer (score 1):

`Delete` button is present in the notifications of Yosemite's (OS X 10.10) version of Mail (8.0).

Sadly, no  `Mark as read` button is available or configurable.